# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, reduce

Typescript newbie here. I'm getting the above error under '**date**' within a reduce array method. I understand I need to declare date as a number instead of string, but unsure how/where?

Thanks in advance!

```
const dates = log?.reduce((dates, order) => {
const date = dateFormat(order.updated_at);
if (!dates[date]) {
  dates[date] = [];
}
dates[date].push(order);
return dates },[])
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, `order` seems to be some object with a property `updated_at` that seems to be a number. In the loop, you format this number into a string and use it to index an object `dates` so that you end up with a mapping of dates to orders on that date.

In Typescript, a map/dictionary are formally called a `Record` and is normally written as `Record<TypeOfKey, TypeOfValue>` to denote a map of `TypeOfKey` to `TypeOfValue`. In older code, you may encounter the old (but still valid) way of defining a record that looks like `{ [key: TypeOfKey]: TypeOfValue }`. The most basic `Record` is a `Record<string, any>`, an object that you can put any data on as long as the property is a string.

Assuming the type of your `order` object is an interface called `Order`, similar to:

```
interface Order {
  updated_at: number;
  /* ... other props ... */
}
```

You would need `dates` to be a `Record<string, Order[]>` (a map with a `string` key that contains an array of `Order` objects). To apply this type to `dates`, you would assign it to the second argument of `reduce()` like so:

```
const dates = log?.reduce((dates, order) => {
  const date = dateFormat(order.updated_at);
  if (!dates[date]) {
    dates[date] = [];
  }
  dates[date].push(order);
  return dates;
}, {} as Record<string, Order[]>); // <-- gives "dates" this type
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it cannot infer `date` type it assumes that it is of any type.

You are trying also to access an array by index `date` so it expects to be of type number so it can access by index.

You can either tell it the date is an integer but since that is probably not your use case you can tell it that your dates is a dictionary

Since I do not know your exact use case here is how you can tell a variable is a dict from string to number

```
dates: { [key: string]: number }
```

Comment: Hey @Freshta I think you can refer to sam's answer it is much more contextual than mine since you don't store a number but instead you store an array of orders as a key. your dates would be of type { [key: string]: [] }